# Wordpress redirects visitors from certain url to their profiles

Tags: wordpress

I am searching for a way to redirect visitors coming  from a certain url to their profiles  in wordpress 
Example if you are coming from example.com/test.html and going to example.com you will be directed to http://www.example.com/author/user/
 Is that possible to be done?  Thanks for help

Comment: you can check where they come from with $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; - And if it matches your url, then wp_redirect() them to their profile page? don't forget to escape the referer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']){
   if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "your test url" && is_user_logged_in()){
       $targetUrl = get_edit_user_link();
       wp_redirect( $targetUrl );
       exit;
   }
}
```

Should do the trick - but escape the referer since its a common attack vector for web apps.

EDIT

If i am reading you question correctly, you want logged in users, to go to their profile page whenever they go to the gomepage?

in that case, you can create a function similar to

```
add_action('wp_head','wpmy_redirect_logged_in_users_away_from_home');
    function wpmy_redirect_logged_in_users_away_from_home() {
        if( is_user_logged_in() && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ) {
            $targetUrl = get_edit_user_link();
            wp_redirect( $targetUrl );
            exit;
        }
     }
```